# Support for the Map data type in SparkSQL while reading CSV file

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV file that contains the Map type data and the Array type data in respective columns. I am trying to create a data frame in SparkSQL, but it throws an error saying that unsupported type map and array. I tried this in both Spark 1.6.3 and Spark 2.2.1. Here is the code:

Spark1.6.3:

```
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    sqlContext=SQLContext(sc)

    customSchema=StructType([StructField("eid",StringType(),True),StructField("username",StringType(),True),StructField("shipping_address",MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True),True),StructField("email_address",StringType(),True),StructField("phone_number",StringType(),True),StructField("ip_address",StringType(),True),StructField("payment_mode",StringType(),True),StructField("billing_amount",IntegerType(),True),StructField("product_details",ArrayType(StringType(),True),True)])

    df1 = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('/data/ordersdata.csv',schema=customSchema)

df1.show()//when I run this command I get an error:"Unsupported type: map"
```

Spark 2.21:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    sqlContext=SQLContext(sc)

    customSchema=StructType([StructField("eid",StringType(),True),StructField("username",StringType(),True),StructField("shipping_address",MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True),True),StructField("email_address",StringType(),True),StructField("phone_number",StringType(),True),StructField("ip_address",StringType(),True),StructField("payment_mode",StringType(),True),StructField("billing_amount",IntegerType(),True),StructField("product_details",ArrayType(StringType(),True),True)])

    df2=spark.read.csv("/data/ordersdata.csv", schema=customSchema, header='true')

df2.show() //when I run this command I get an error:"Unsupported type: map"
```

Actually, my requirement is to extract the key-value pairs from the map type column in the CSV file and create new columns with keys as the column headers and store the respective values in them in the same dataframe. For example, the map data in the CSV file looks like this:

```
{"address_line":"Ridge 2897","zip_code":"15201","city":"Pittsburgh","state":"Pennsylvania","phone_no":"9832901309"}
```

Now, I want to create columns as shown below and add them to the main data frame, which is created using the CSV file.

```
address_line | zip_code  |  city       |  state       |  phone_no 
Ridge 2897   | 15201     | Pittsburgh  | Pennsylvania | 9832901309
```

Comment: provide  your sample CSV file,so that we can help you

Comment: @devesh, here is the sample csv data:

Comment: @devesh, here is the sample csv data:


eid,username,shipping_address
1001,John,"{""address_line"":""Ridge 2897"",""zip_code"":""15201"",""city"":""Pittsburgh"",""state"":""Pennsylvania"",""phone_no"":""9832901309""}" 4366"",""zip_code"":""30381"",""city"":""Atlanta"",""state"":""Georgia"",""phone_no"":""4538659123""}"
1003,Norman,"{""address_line"":""sunset 3653"",""zip_code"":""90039"",""city"":""Los Angeles"",""state"":""California"",""phone_no"":""7632894032""}"